# Removing white space in a table

Tags: latex, whitespace

I am having an issue with too much white space. Here's a picture of my data fields with placeholders representing the largest digit count possible in them.

[image]

As you can see, after the last "P" the values escape the scope of the chart. While I could increase the size of the table as a whole (currently textwidth), that would be a poor design choice on my part. What I'm thinking is to utilize all of that wasted white space. I don't know what to do though.

When I have all single digit values, the table looks perfect. I want the increased number size to "consume" the white space before forcing the table out of it's defined bounds.
I was hoping using extracolsep with no arguments would remove whitespace, but it sadly does not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try adding this command before your table;

\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1pt}

the default column separator width is 6pt inserted before and after column contents, but this will change that. Replace 1pt with whatever you need.

Comment: That's it exactly! What a simple, clean fix.